# there's a problem in data transformation in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i need an help to do the following in google sheets through google app script
i have data formatted in a table as

```
A C
A D
A E
B F
B G
B H
```

i need a code to transform this data into

```
A C D E 
B F G H
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `i have data formatted in a table as A C A D A E B F B G B H`? Is each value put into each cell in rows or columns?

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunk() { 
  let arr = ["A","C","A","D","A","E","B","F","B","G","B","H"];
  let arr1 = [...new Set(arr)];
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(arr1));
}

Execution log
4:15:39 PM  Notice  Execution started
4:15:38 PM  Info    ["A","C","D","E","B","F","G","H"]
4:15:41 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use a pivot table but I'm not good at those.  Instead I have this sample script that will construct a table as you show.  I've added an additional B value just to show how to make sure the array is compatible with `setValues()`.

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    console.log(values);
    let a = values.map( row => row[0] );
    // first get the unique values in column A
    a = [... new Set(a)];
    // now make it a 2D array
    let b = a.map( row => [row] );
    console.log(b);
    let j = 0;
    values.forEach( row => {
        let i = a.findIndex( c => c === row[0] );
        b[i].push(row[1]);
        j = b[i].length > j ? b[i].length : j;
      }
    );
    console.log("j = "+j)
    console.log(b);
    // construct an array of blanks to fill in the rows
    let c = [];
    c.length = j;
    c.fill("");
    console.log(c);
    // now lets make sure each row is the same length so we can use setValues()
    b.forEach( (row,i) => {
        if( row.length < j ) {
          b[i] = row.concat(c.slice(0,j-row.length))
        }
      }
    );
    console.log(b)
    
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Execution log**

```
6:51:07 AM  Notice  Execution started
6:51:08 AM  Info    [ [ 'A', 'C' ],
  [ 'A', 'D' ],
  [ 'A', 'E' ],
  [ 'B', 'F' ],
  [ 'B', 'G' ],
  [ 'B', 'H' ],
  [ 'B', 'I' ] ]
6:51:08 AM  Info    [ [ 'A' ], [ 'B' ] ]
6:51:08 AM  Info    j = 5
6:51:08 AM  Info    [ [ 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E' ], [ 'B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I' ] ]
6:51:08 AM  Info    [ '', '', '', '', '' ]
6:51:08 AM  Info    [ [ 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', '' ], [ 'B', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I' ] ]
6:51:08 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

**Reference**

- [Array.map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
- [Set object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Array.findIndex()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp)
- [Array.push()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)
- [Array.fill()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fill.asp)
- [Array.concat()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp)
- [Array.slice()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp)
- [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)